# No inspection system is available for object of type <type 'instancemethod'> when kickstarting apache server

Tags: windows, ubuntu, airflow

I am following steps on this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYOUbiGtGiU
After that I run this :
airflow webserver -p 8060

And it is giving this stacktrace:

```
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/
[2020-04-08 19:32:06,906] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2020-04-08 19:32:06,907] {dagbag.py:403} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/fatima/airflow/dags
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 37, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 75, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 900, in webserver
    app = cached_app_rbac(None) if settings.RBAC else cached_app(None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 233, in cached_app
    app = create_app(config, testing)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 103, in create_app
    models.Chart, Session, name="Charts", category="Data Profiling"))
  File "/home/fatima/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py", line 330, in __init__
    menu_icon_value=menu_icon_value)
  File "/home/fatima/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 818, in __init__
    self._refresh_cache()
  File "/home/fatima/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 913, in _refresh_cache
    self._search_supported = self.init_search()
  File "/home/fatima/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py", line 581, in init_search
    if tools.is_hybrid_property(self.model, name):
  File "/home/fatima/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/tools.py", line 209, in is_hybrid_property
    return last_name in get_hybrid_properties(last_model)
  File "/home/fatima/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/tools.py", line 190, in get_hybrid_properties
    for key, prop in inspect(model).all_orm_descriptors.items()
  File "/home/fatima/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/inspection.py", line 72, in inspect
    "available for object of type %s" % type_
sqlalchemy.exc.NoInspectionAvailable: No inspection system is available for object of type <type 'instancemethod'>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was getting the same error today, Found the solution here (Also from today) [Airflow webserver not getting start shows error sqlalchemy.exc.NoInspectionAvailable: No inspection system is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61101729/airflow-webserver-not-getting-start-shows-error-sqlalchemy-exc-noinspectionavail)

For a temporary solution you need to downgrade sql alchemy to version 1.3.15

```
pip3 uninstall SQLAlchemy
pip3 install SQLAlchemy==1.3.15
```

Comment: I tried but when I run it in the command it opens up this script: import argcomplete

from airflow.configuration import conf
from airflow.bin.cli import CLIFactory

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if conf.get("core", "security") == 'kerberos':
        os.environ['KRB5CCNAME'] = conf.get('kerberos', 'ccache')
        os.environ['KRB5_KTNAME'] = conf.get('kerberos', 'keytab')

    parser = CLIFactory.get_parser()
    argcomplete.autocomplete(parser)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    args.func(args)

Comment: @pinkpuffles, Looks like that maybe a different issue. Something to do with Windows Authentication (Kerberos)?