# I am trying to launch airflow webserver. But it throughs error. I have installed pymysql using pip as well successfully

Tags: airflow

I am trying to launch airflow webserver. But it throughs error. I have installed pymysql using pip as well successfully. I need help in fixing the issue.

Here is the error code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/next_tech/airflow-env/bin/airflow", line 37, in 
>       args.func(args)   File "/Users/next_tech/airflow-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py",
>   line 75, in wrapper
>       return f(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/next_tech/airflow-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py",
>   line 900, in webserver
>       app = cached_app_rbac(None) if settings.RBAC else cached_app(None)   File
>   "/Users/next_tech/airflow-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py",
>   line 233, in cached_app
>       app = create_app(config, testing)   File "/Users/next_tech/airflow-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py",
>   line 103, in create_app
>       models.Chart, Session, name="Charts", category="Data Profiling"))   File
>   "/Users/next_tech/airflow-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py",
>   line 330, in **init**
>       menu_icon_value=menu_icon_value)   File "/Users/next_tech/airflow-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py",
>   line 818, in **init**
>       self._refresh_cache()   File "/Users/next_tech/airflow-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py",
>   line 913, in _refresh_cache
>       self._search_supported = self.init_search()   File "/Users/next_tech/airflow-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py",
>   line 581, in init_search
>       if tools.is_hybrid_property(self.model, name):   File "/Users/next_tech/airflow-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/tools.py",
>   line 209, in is_hybrid_property
>       return last_name in get_hybrid_properties(last_model)   File "/Users/next_tech/airflow-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/tools.py",
>   line 190, in get_hybrid_properties
>       for key, prop in inspect(model).all_orm_descriptors.items()   File "/Users/next_tech/airflow-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/inspection.py",
>   line 72, in inspect
>       "available for object of type %s" % type_ sqlalchemy.exc.NoInspectionAvailable: No inspection system is
>   available for object of type  (airflow-env)
>   Nexts-MacBook-Pro:airflow_home next_tech$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to pin the SQLAlchemy==1.3.15 as this is a duplicate of [Starting Airflow webserver fails with sqlalchemy.exc.NoInspectionAvailable: No inspection system is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61101729/starting-airflow-webserver-fails-with-sqlalchemy-exc-noinspectionavailable-no-i)